# Sharing memory, как межпроцессное взаимодействие

Tags: процесс, memory, ос, sharing

Встретил один из видов межпроцессного взаимодействия sharing memory (shared memory). Хотелось бы узнать, как там все происходит, да и вообще про использование shm в целом.

Answer (score 1):

[https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Разделяемая_память](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) - если Вам нужно совсем кратко, то википедию никто не отменял) Правда, это называется не sharing, а shared memory.

По поводу реализации: в Linux, к примеру, объекты Shared Memory реализованы посредством специальной файловой системы, монтируемой к /dev/shm. Вызов POSIX функции `shm_open("name", ...)` будет эквивалентен системному вызову `open("/dev/shm/name", ...)`.

В Winows, если Вам интересно использование этого механизма - посмотрите пример на MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx